# Delete struct from stack memory

Tags: c, memory, struct, null, stack

I have a linked list struct, i want to pass one node (another struct) pointer to a function (the node is part of the linked list, but i'm passing the node seperately to a deleter function

I want it to copy the next node data into itself (overriding its data), and to delete the next node, thus deleting itself (this part is working)..
I made it check whether the passed node is the last node in the list, and if so, to delete itself.

I don't know how to delete structs from the stack (i know i can malloc() and free() it using the heap memory).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int data;
    struct node * next;
}node;

typedef struct {
    struct node * head;
}linked_list;

void print_list(linked_list * list) {

    node *current = list->head;
    while (current) {
        printf("Current node has %d\n",current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
}

void delete_node(node * n) {
    node * next = n->next;
    if (next) {
        n->data = next->data;
        n->next = next->next;
    }
    else {
        *n =  NULL; /*This of course won't compile because assigning void* (null) to node variable
                              but if i make n point to NULL, nothing will happen because i'm inside a function
                              and the pointer is duplicated (the passed pointer will still work) */
    }
}

void main(){
    node first;
    node second;
    first.data = 1;
    first.next = &second;
    second.data = 2;
    second.next = NULL;
    linked_list l;
    l.head = &first;
    print_list(&l);
    delete_node(&second);
    print_list(&l);
}
```

Comment: Local variables do not get deleted... you simply terminate the local block to release that memory.

Comment: But i'm passing a pointer to a function, the variable i want to delete is not in the range of the function. does it mean i simply can't do what i'm trying to?

Comment: You can unlink from your list, but you cannot delete the memory taken by the structure. You can only delete that which you first allocate, and generally in the same manner. Since your allocation was implicit (by starting the execution block), your releasing will also be implicit (by terminating the execution block).

Comment: Thanks... any way to unlink a given node inside a function? (with access only to that node)

Comment: unlinking a node and deleting the memory occupied by that node are separate tasks... it's certainly possible to do that within a function since unlinking it is simply a matter of ejecting it from your linked list: find the previous node in the list and set prevNode's next pointer to be the current node's next pointer. It doesn't look like your example is doing that though you seem to be copying the node rather than changing the links -- probably not what you mean to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, **you can't**.

If you want to be able to store both allocated (by `malloc`) and non-allocated (static or automatic) storage objects in your list and have a "delete" function that removes objects from the list and frees them, you need to store as part of each list member a flag indicating whether it's in allocated storage or not, and only free the ones which are.

Also note that you'll be in big trouble if the lifetime of the structure with automatic storage ends before you remove it from the list! If dealing with this is confusing at all for you, then you would probably be better-off just using allocated storage (`malloc`) for all list members.

Answer (score 1):

You can't   :)

On most computer architectures, local variables are either allocated directly on a CPU register or on the stack. For local variables allocated on the stack, the top of the stack (the same stack that is used to hold the return addresses of function calls) is  manipulated to make space for them when a function enters, and it is restored to "release" the memory when the function exits.  All this stack management is handled automatically by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'free' operator for freeing / deleting a malloc assigned object in the memory. For that, in your code you can write :

```
free(n);
```