# Deleting a struct instance

Tags: c

```
{
    int degree;
    double *coeff; 
};

struct poly create_poly()
{// Ask the user to enter the degree of the polynomial and (degree +1) coefficients
    struct poly p;
    printf("Power of the polynomial : ");
    scanf("%d", &p.degree);
    p.coeff = malloc((p.degree + 1) * sizeof *p.coeff);
    for (int i = 0; i <= p.degree; i++)
    {// Read a double as coeff
        printf("Enter the coeff x^%d : ", i);
        scanf("%lf", &p.coeff[i]);
    }
    return p;
}

int main{
 struct poly p1 = create_poly();
 struct poly p2 = create_poly();
struct poly p3 = create_poly();
}
```

Suppose i have a struct that looks like `struct poly`. I have a function which creates the instances of the struct i.e `create_poly`. The main function is where the function is used to create the instances. Say i want to delete instance p2. How do i go on about it?
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I think the explanations that are given in the following links can answer your question:
[Deleting all structure entries in C Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186641/deleting-all-structure-entries-in-c-programming)

[Delete struct from stack memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179169/delete-struct-from-stack-memory)

Comment: Please provide quotes of related parts from the resources you are sharing next time. This way more inexperienced users can find their way more easily.

Comment: @Meto You are right. Thanks for letting me know. I will do it next time. Just denoting that In both links I found more than one good answer to the above question.